# A lot of variables in a Quadratic Discriminant Analysis

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis, errors-in-variables

I'm trying to make a Quadratic Discriminant Analysis in R, but appears the follow mistake: "some group is too small for 'qda'". I was reading about it and I concluded that I have more columns (variables) than rows in a level of my categorical variable. Then, I want to know what criteria could I use to delete more variables. Initially I had about 90 variables, and I studied the multicollinearity and I deleted about 70, but I don't know how to delete more variables using a "statistical reason" to make it work the QDA.

Thanks for help!

Comment: why not pivot away from QDA if it doesn't seem to be appropriate for your data set? Bienvenidos to the site btw, César. (PS: "error in variables" refers to the case when you hvaen't measured your variables correctly, which may not be what you had in mind).

Comment: Are your variables factors or continuous?

Comment: @PeterFlom continuos. The levels of categorical variables isn't a factor in R

Comment: @JohnMaden thanks for correction! On other hand, I have to make a Linear Discriminant Analysis, but the hypothesis about variance-covariance matrix don't met, then I'm trying now with the QDA.

Comment: Then I think they have gotten misread as categorical. This happens a lot in R.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481772/r-error-some-group-is-too-small-for-qda